# How to remove focus on button when reading data from scanner barcode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, barcode-scanner

**Problem**

How to remove focus on button when reading data from scanner ?

**Details**

I need to read data from bar code scanner to windows form .

i can read data success without any problem

my problem is if i put the button in form it focus on it and not reading data

so that how to add button to form  and remove focus on it when reading data

this is actually my problem i need to solve .

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DateTime _lastKeystroke = new DateTime(0);
        List<char> _barcode = new List<char>(10);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
            if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
                _barcode.Clear();

            // record keystroke & timestamp
            _barcode.Add(e.KeyChar);
            _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;

            // process barcode
            if (e.KeyChar == 13 && _barcode.Count > 0)
            {
                string msg = new String(_barcode.ToArray());


                _barcode.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can any one help me if possible

Comment: i not found answer in the posted link